# R- format a data.frame into another 'combined' data.frame based on common values within a column dependent across different columns

Tags: r

I'm starting with a data frame that consists of three columns.
Column#1 contains ids that indicate 3 different time periods when the weight (column#3) of some persons (column#2) has been measured in kg.

All persons have been measured irregularly, which means, that some persons are measured multiple times or just once within a time period but not across all time periods.

```
   id       person_name person_weight
    1          Carol         51
    1          Mike          76
    1          Mike          81
    1          Dave          66
    1          Carol         59
    2          James         78
    2          Simone        55
    2          Simone        49
    2          David         85
    3          Mike          93
    3          Dave          110
    3          Dave          98
```

Actually, the whole thing here is just a simplified example.. so dont bother if this kind of data collections makes no sense.

Now, I want to calculate the average (mean) weight for each person within a time period and then
end up with a combined data frame that looks like the following one:

```
group_id    Carol   Mike    Dave    James   Simone  David
   1         55     78.5     66      NA       NA     NA
   2         NA      NA      NA      78       52     85
   3         NA      93      104     NA       NA     NA
```

I tried some basic R functions (table, apply etc.) but couldn’t deal with the dependence across the columns.

Thanks in advance for any help that brings me closer to the second/'combined' dataframe.

Comment: Some vocabulary would be helpful here, I think.  Your first data set, where each *measurement* is a separate record, is called `long` format data.  There are two corresponding `wide` formats: one with a row for each group (the one you want), and one with a row for each person.  Switching between long and wide formats is generally called `reshaping`; we `melt` wide data into long data and `cast` long data into wide data.  These are powerful concepts, and `reshape2` is a great implementation of them - makes life so much easier.  Well worth taking the time to learn.

Comment: "Well worth taking the time to learn". Joran's solution approved your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a simple `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat,id ~person_name,
      fun.aggregate = mean,
      value.var = "person_weight",fill = NA_real_)
  id Carol Dave David James Mike Simone
1  1    55   66    NA    NA 78.5     NA
2  2    NA   NA    85    78   NA     52
3  3    NA  104    NA    NA 93.0     NA
```